# How to determine $\partial_x f(x(r,\Theta),y(r,\Theta)) = f(r \cdot \cos(\Theta), r \cdot \sin(\Theta))$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is the derivative even expressible? I can't really simplify the expression, unless saying it's equal to: $\partial_x  f(r \cdot \cos(\Theta), r \cdot \sin(\Theta))$.

Or do I have to apply some chain-rule?

I could also be equal to $\partial_x x(r,\Theta) \cdot \partial_xf + \partial_xy(r,\Theta)\cdot \partial_yf$. But doesn't make a lot of sense to me since no x really occurs in the expanded equations.

Comment: What does $\partial _x f(r\cos(\Theta),r\sin(\Theta))$ means? $x$ is not a variable, your variables are $r$ and $\Theta$.

Comment: That's why I was asking. Only thing given is $x = x(r,\Theta) = r\cdot cos(\Theta)$